# Send accumulated requests to webservice - RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android, rx-java2

I have add button in my app to let user add item to a list, if user clicks the add button i dont the request to go to the webservice immediately, I want the request to be accumulated and sent every 1 seconds with the total number of clicks. instead of sending the request every time the user clicks the add button.

I saw that there is something like this implemented for RxSearchView. I checked the code it is too complicated

I need some help with where should I start with such a problem ? or any ready solution for this ?

Comment: (1req/sec) per user, I don't want to be in your server's place.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin I meant to send the requests accumulated every 1 second instead of sending it every time the user clicks the add button. Sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `debounce` operator:

> Returns an Observable that mirrors the source ObservableSource, except that it drops items emitted by the source ObservableSource that are followed by newer items before a timeout value expires. The timer resets on each emission.[image]

Just wrap your click events into `Observable`:

```
Observable<Object> getButtonObservable(final Button button) {
    return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<Object> e) throws Exception {
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    e.onNext(new Object()); //instead of Object you can use any data, e.g. derived from View tag
                }
            });
            e.setCancellable(new Cancellable() {
                @Override
                public void cancel() throws Exception {
                    button.setOnClickListener(null);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And apply that operator not forgetting to unsubscribe in `onDestroy` (`onDestroyView`):

```
Button addButton;
Disposable addButtonDisposable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    getButtonObservable(addButton)
            .doOnSubscribe(new Consumer<Disposable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Disposable disposable) throws Exception {
                    addButtonDisposable = disposable;
                }
            })
            .debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            ... //make request using flatMap or doOnNext, and subscribe
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    addButtonDisposable.dispose();
}
```

Comment: great, thank you soo much, one last question, is it possible to make a custom view with the onClickListener is set to the debounce observable ? thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can wrap any callback in any class. `Observable.create` is meant for such cases.

Comment: By the way, I fixed my answer - `e.setCancelable` moved out of `onClick` callback.